# Symmetry conjecture for minimal dilatation pseudo Anosov mapping classes

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

The conjecture is something like the following:

The minimal dilatation among pseudo-Anosov mapping classes on a surface $S_{g,n}$ is realized by $\rho\circ\omega$ where $\omega$ is supported on a subsurface and $\rho$ is finite order.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any work towards this conjecture or a reference for a statement of it.

Comment: Constructions of this sort are made in this paper, but no conjecture stated: http://msp.org/gt/2009/13-4/p10.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

[Update]

Margalit has been stating a more precise version of this conjecture since at least 2012.  See page 38 of these [slides](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/annexes/conferences/MCG2012/slides/Margalit3.pdf).

[Old version]

There is related work by several people.  I could not find a statement of the conjecture, but I have heard versions of it - sometimes it is generalized to more than just the minimal dilatation pA map. Instead, there is a statement about all pA maps satisfying certain bounds.  Here are a few relevant references.

- Small dilatation pseudo-Anosovs and 3–manifolds - by Benson Farb, Christopher J. Leininger, and Dan Margalit.
- Ideal triangulations of pseudo-Anosov mapping tori - by Ian Agol.
- Penner sequences and asymptotics of minimum dilatations for subfamilies of the mapping class group - by Eriko Hironaka